# XPath to get element with children containing specific text for Puppeteeer clicking

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, puppeteer, e2e-testing

I am struggling to use Puppeteer's `page.$x(XPath)` to get an element which has a child node containing a certain text. Here's the format of the HTML I am trying to test:

```
<custom-radio>
    <div>
        ....
    </div>
    <input>
    <span>
        <span><b>Country </b></span> 
        <span>Afghanistan</span>
    </span>
</custom-radio>

<custom-radio>
    <div>
        ....
    </div>
    <input>
    <span>
        <span><b>Country </b></span> 
        <span>France</span>
    </span>
</custom-radio>
```

In my code, I am navigating to the URL using Puppeteer (`await page.goto(url)`) and trying to click on the radio button for a specific country. I have looked at other posts and tried to use the XPath expressions with no luck. Here is one:

```
const exp = '//span[.//*[contains(text(), "France")]]';
const result = await page.$x(exp);
console.log(result.length); //this is always 0
```

I have also tried using this XPath expression and I got the same result:

```
const result = await page.$x('//input[.//*contains(., "France")]');
await page.click(result[0]);
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Could I please get some help in achieving the above? Thanks!

Comment: Your xpath expression is correct. It may be something to do with the waiting. See if this helps: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3643#issuecomment-445575784.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JackFleeting - adding `page.waitForXPath` did the trick.